# Separate mobile site

Tags: mobile

So, I have a desktop site that has lots of features and design specific contents which are not really suitable for mobile view (loading speed etc).

So, I want to have a separate mobile site, such as `m.example.com`.

I am thinking of somehow detecting  that it is in either mobile or tablet view.

What would be the most appropriate tutorial that is up to date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for a good overview of what you might want (to do further research), you might want to take a look at this question: [How to make Mobile website like m.yahoo.com (Mobile Version)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653726/how-to-make-mobile-website-like-m-yahoo-com-mobile-version)

For a good tutorial, I'm not sure if you're asking for a text tutorial or a video tutorial. I find that text tutorials give you options to go at your own pace and dive deeper in the subject. Therefore, I would suggest this tutorial: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/responsivedesign/

Wish you best of luck with your developing

Comment: Thank you for the info. Appreciate it. :-)